# Given the curve $\alpha(s)=(a \cos\frac{s}{c}, a \sin\frac{s}{c}, b\frac{s}{c})$ show that the tangent lines make a constant angle with the $z$ axis

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

> Given the parametrized curve $\alpha(s)=\left(a \cos\frac{s}{c}, a \sin\frac{s}{c}, b\frac{s}{c}\right), s \in \mathbb R, $
>   where $c^2=a^2+b^2$, show that the tangent lines to $\alpha$ make a constant angle with the $z$ axis.

The tangent lines are given by $$\alpha(s)+t\alpha'(s)=\left(a \cos\frac{s}{c}, a \sin\frac{s}{c}, b\frac{s}{c}\right)+t\left( -\frac{a}{c} \sin\frac{s}{c}, \frac{a}{c} \cos\frac{s}{c}, \frac{b}{c}\right).$$

For the $z$ axis, we can use the vector $(0,0,1)$.

I am trying to compute $$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(\alpha(s)+t\alpha'(s))\cdot (0,0,1)}{|\alpha(s)+t\alpha'(s)||(0,0,1)|}\right)$$
but I am not getting a constant angle.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You are right that the tangent line is $\alpha(s)+t\alpha'(s)$, but you only need the direction vector of that line, i.e., $\alpha'(s)$. So, you have to compute$$\frac{\alpha'(s)\cdot (0,0,1)}{|\alpha'(s)|\cdot|(0,0,1)|},$$which is constantly $\tfrac bc$.